# Keyup event cancel keydown repeat

Tags: javascript, event-listener, keydown, keyup

This code is part of 30 Day Vanilla JS Challenge.

If you keep a sound key press, the sound keeps on playing without being able to notice 'ended' event (removing of 'playing' class) except for 'D' and 'L' because sound duration is too short (~0.16s and ~0.04s respectively).

But there's two thing that I don't really understand :

1. When you have 'A' pressed and you press another sound key (and keeps
   it down), the previousy pressed key ('A') stops 'looping' and waits
   the new sound key to end before 'looping' all together again. But
   from the code I wrote, if the key is down (in keyStatus map) it
   should play the sound
2. If I have one or several key(s) down, the sound is 'looping' but
   once I trigger a keyup all the others keys that are still down stop
   triggering their event. How does JS handle those cases ?

I hope I was clear enough

```js
const allAudio = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
    allAudio.forEach(audio => audio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
      let dataKey = audio.getAttribute('data-key');
      document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${dataKey}"]`).classList.remove('playing');
    }));
    
    let keyStatus = {};

    window.addEventListener('keyup', e => handleKeyPress(e));

    window.addEventListener('keydown', e => handleKeyPress(e));

    function handleKeyPress(event) {
      console.log(event);
      if(event.key === undefined)
        return;
      
      keyStatus[event.key] = event.type === "keydown";

      for(key in keyStatus) {
        if(keyStatus[key])
          playSound(key);
      }
    }

    function playSound(dataKey) {
      let key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${dataKey}"]`);
      let audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${dataKey}"]`);

      if(key) {
        key.classList.add('playing');
      }

      if(audio) {
        audio.play();
      }
    }
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/b9r5sEL.jpg) bottom center;
  background-size: cover;
}

body,html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.key {
  border: .4rem solid black;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s ease;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem black;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: #ffc600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #ffc600;
}

kbd {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.sound {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  color: #ffc600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JS Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="keys">
    <div data-key="a" class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="s" class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="d" class="key">
      <kbd>D</kbd>
      <span class="sound">kick</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="f" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">openhat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="g" class="key">
      <kbd>G</kbd>
      <span class="sound">boom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="h" class="key">
      <kbd>H</kbd>
      <span class="sound">ride</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="j" class="key">
      <kbd>J</kbd>
      <span class="sound">snare</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="k" class="key">
      <kbd>K</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="l" class="key">
      <kbd>L</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tink</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <audio data-key="a" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="s" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="d" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="f" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="g" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="h" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="j" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="k" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="l" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did not try running your code. but it seems that you are missing "reset" step when a key is released.